# Understanding EOF and break

Tags: c, break

I am trying to write a program which replaces a string of one or more tabs by a single tab.

Here's what I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n')
    {
        if (c == 9)
        {
            while((c=getchar())== 9)
                putchar('   ');
            if (c != 9)
                break;
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
}
```

I compared it to newline because I don't get EOF and pressing ctrl-z does nothing, atleast on Windows.
Well the output prints spaces instead of tabs. Can someone point out what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: `putchar('\t');` ?

Comment: Are you asking how to use something like ctrl-z to break out of your while loop? Or about replacing the tabs in a string - which you seem to suggets is working

Comment: Please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). Fixing logical errors in your algorithm is a job for you the developer in a debugging session, not a topic for a SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to `break`, in fact, when you use `break` inside a `for`/`while` you exit from the loop (not what you want), if you want to allow only one tab use a sentinel and `continue` if the previous character is also a tab:

```
int c, tab = 0;

while (((c = getchar()) != '\n') && (c != EOF))  {
    if (c == '\t') {
        if (tab == 1) continue;
        tab = 1;
    } else {
        tab = 0;
    }
    putchar(c);
}
```

Press CTRL+ Z + Intro to send `EOF` in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

its because you write `putchar('    ')`.

its an error.  write `putchar('\t')` instead.

there is no such char as `'    '`. this is 4 spaces.